# Stack Overflow notification sender does not pass sender address verification check

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-exchange, email-notification

Tons of SMTP servers on the Internet include the "[Sender Address Verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification)" (SAV) check.
The notification mails of Stack Exchange sites (SO, Meta, and probably all others too) do not pass that test (in this case the test is performed by [smf-sav](http://smfs.sourceforge.net/smf-sav.html)):

> Sep 13 07:41:58 snap smf-sav[27873]: sender check tempfailed: , 69.59.196.214, mail1.stackoverflow.com, [00:01:00]

Since the SAV settings, and sometimes even whitelists, are often out of reach for the recipient, many users will not receive the notification mails.

I know that the sender e-mail for notification mails (like `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com`, `do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com`, *et cetera*) should not be replied to, but I don't think that denying the existence of them is not the nicest way to solve the not-replying option.

Note: I know that SAV is not always the most optimum solution to prevent spam, but it is a given that it is used a lot.

**Edit 20100928:**

The fix works only partially. You need to add the other "SE" do-not-reply addresses as well.

For example, the SMTP server at `mail1.stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.214]` does not accept `do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com` as a valid email address.

Here are some log-file entries:

```
Sep 25 03:33:36 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: NOQUEUE: connect from mail1.stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.214]
Sep 25 03:33:56 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: o8P1XalG006766: Milter (smf-sav): init success to negotiate
Sep 25 03:33:56 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: o8P1XalG006766: Milter (smf-grey): init success to negotiate
Sep 25 03:33:56 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: o8P1XalG006766: Milter: connect to filters
Sep 25 03:34:56 snap smf-sav[27873]: sender check tempfailed: <do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com>, 69.59.196.214, mail1.stackoverflow.com, [00:01:00]
Sep 25 03:34:57 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: o8P1XalG006766: Milter: from=<do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com>, reject=451 4.1.8 Sender address verification in progress
Sep 25 03:34:57 snap sm-mta-rx[6766]: o8P1XalG006766: from=<do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com>, size=4427, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-RX, relay=mail1.stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.214]
```

--jeroen

Comment: I've probably been under a stone too long: Is StackExchange the rebrand of the generic StackOveflow?

Comment: yup.  StackExchange is the software behind sites like SO, SF, SU, and all of the new sites too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is literally the *first time I have ever heard of anyone having this issue* after over a year of sending emails, the "fix" seems harmless enough. I went ahead and created

`do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com`

as an email account on the domain.

Comment: Thanks. But your current solution only works for this particular email address, not for the do-not-reply addresses used by other SE sites. See my edit in the question.