# feature request: on accounts bound to your SO login, show on SO what activity (answers, comments) you had on the other SO-based sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, notifications

I primarily use StackOverflow, but also ask questions on SuperUser, ServerFault, etc.

All my accounts are linked to the same login, but since I don't get email notifications (because of this [SAV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64331/stack-overflow-notification-sender-does-not-pass-sender-address-verification-chec) issue) it usually takes me a couple of days to notice something interesting happened to my questions/answers/comments/favourites on the other sites.

So it would be great if (when your accounts are linked) you get some visual indication that some of the other sites have news for you too.

--jeroen